# Необходимо оптимизировать программу

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, математика

Есть следующая задача по информатике:
Никитино любимое занятие скадывать из камешков правильные треугольники. Он и не предполагал, что числа, из которых можно сложить правильный треугольник называются треугольными. Помогите по заданному кол-ву N камешков найти наибольшую сторону правильного треугольника, который из них можно сложить. Например для N=30 ответ будет 7. Тесты для проверки:

1. 30 - 7
2. 29 - 7
3. 27 - 6
4. 9876543210000 - 4444443
5. 9223372036854775807 - 4294967295

Для первых 4 тестов у меня время выполнение приемлемое( не более 2 сек для 4 теста), но для 5 спустя и 3 минуты ответ не вышел. Нужно оптимизировать следующий код, либо написать лучше. Писал код исходя из формулы нахождения треугольного числа T = 1/2*n*(n + 1). Необходимо либо оптимизировать следующий код, либо написать лучше

```
import math
a = int(input())
n = int(math.ceil(math.sqrt(a)))
res = 0.5*n*(n + 1)
while res <= a:
    n += 1
    res = 0.5*n*(n + 1)
print(n - 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, то можно так:

```
import math
n = int(input())

print(math.floor((math.sqrt(n*8+1)-1)/2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, используя свойство биномиального коэффициента:

```
import math
a = int(input())
n = int(math.sqrt(a*2))
res = 0.5*n*(n + 1)
while res > a:
    n -= 1
    res = 0.5*n*(n + 1)
print(n)
```